# Can to_representation() in Django Rest Framework access the normal fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The docs on using `to_representation` is somewhat short.  This method is used by `Django Rest Framework 3.0+` to change the representation of your data in an API.

Here' the documentation link:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

Here is my current code:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

class PersonListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('foo', 'bar',)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return model_to_dict(instance)
```

When I do this code, it returns all fields in the model instead of the fields that I have specified above in `class Meta: fields`.

Is it possible to reference the `class Meta: fields` within the `to_representation` method?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but they call `self._readable_fields` in the source. https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L438

Answer (score 82, accepted):

DRF's `ModelSerializer` already has all the logic to handle that. In your case you shouldn't even need to customize `to_representation`. If you need to customize it, I would recommend to first call super and then customize the output:

```
class PersonListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('foo', 'bar',)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(PersonListSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data.update(...)
        return data
```

---

P.S. if you are interested to know how it works, the magic actually does not happen in `ModelSerializer.to_representation`. As a matter of fact, it does not even implement that method. Its implemented on regular [`Serializer`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L438-L458). All the magic with Django models actually happens in [`get_fields`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L867) which calls [`get_field_names`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L936) which then considers the `Meta.fields` parameters...

Comment: Hi, Is there any way we can pass the serializer name dynamically here:- `data = super(PersonListSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)`

Comment: That's the correct answer, also many suggesting making a method field. While to_representation is their to do this type of stuff !

Answer (score 2):

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(ResultLogSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    data['username'] = instance.job_result.user.username
    data['status'] = instance.job_result.status
    data['created'] = instance.job_result.created
    data['completed'] = instance.job_result.completed
    return data
```