# Django serializing / deserializing two values to one model field

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have this code:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Driver(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)
    accuracy = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Driver

class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = '__all__'
```

The PointField is serialized into

```
{"location":"SRID=4326;POINT (106.84341430665 -6.1832427978516)"}
```

but I would like to get

```
{"latitude": 106.84341430665, "longitude": -6.1832427978516}
```

when serializing and also use this format for deserializing. Is it possible to do this inside the serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two serializer method field which accepts `obj` as the second parameter. Then you can process `longitude` and `latitude` using those method.

You can also write custom serializer field or override the `to_representation` method of the serializer. Here's an example: [Can to_representation() in Django Rest Framework access the normal fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820389/can-to-representation-in-django-rest-framework-access-the-normal-fields).

The 2nd one might be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you masnun for pointing to the right direction. This is what I came up with:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from .models import Driver

class DriverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    location = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    latitude = serializers.FloatField()
    longitude = serializers.FloatField()
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_location(self, obj):
        return Point(obj.latitude, obj.longitude)    

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super(DriverSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        lat, lon = ret['location'].coords
        ret['latitude'] = lat
        ret['longitude'] = lon
        del ret['location']
        return ret
```

Deserialization (json -> model) is handled by adding two new fields to the DriverSerializer, overwriting the existing "location" field with `SerializerMethodField` and implementing the `get_<field_name>`.  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

The `to_representation` deals with the serialization (model -> json) part.

Comment: For PointField, it should be initialized using `Point(obj.longitude, obj.latitude)`

Comment: How do you deserialize it?